# Argument list too long - echo in container

Tags: docker, container

The container is running a Ruby Application that will generate a huge string (not sure how huge) and I am storing it in a variable (index_render) and appending that into a file.

```
system("echo '#{index_render}' > temp/temp.html")
```

But I am getting `Errno::E2BIG: [!] Argument list too long - echo`

I am using a container alpine/bundle:2.7.2 that will run a ruby application and inside the application, ruby will call a node application. So I am installing nvm, node, etc from the alpine/bundle:2.7.2 image as init script (like provisioning script).

Is there any way to increase the size using the init script? as I don't have access to modify the Ruby application.

Comment: You could use `xargs`?

Comment: @barrycarter Unfortunately I cannot edit the line `system("echo '#{index_render}' > temp/temp.html")` that is from Ruby application (3ed party app). That's why I was looking for some solution which I can do inside container.

Comment: https://docs.opensvc.com/latest/_static/argmax.html may or may not be helpful. If I skimmed correctly, this is an OS limit and would require recompiling the kernel. You might want to mention which shell the container is using.

Answer (score 1):

This because `system()` in many languages calls through actual shell, by default `/bin/sh`.

There might be several problems:

- the text in variable contains `'` character many times, which breaks `'` wrapping the variable into many small bits until number of arguments is exhausted
- the text expanded from variable is too big to parse for shell, that is being invoked by `system()`, so the shell dies with this error
- the text expanded from variable is really too big to fit into the `argv` kernel buffer

Why don't you fix application to write into target file directly by default, without intermediary "echo +variable + shell redirect" step?